# What components (parts) are needed to connect telescope to DSLR?

Tags: photography

I have several years of experience with DSLR photography and some astro photography (milkyway) with DSLR. Recently, my wife gifted me an explore scientific ED80 APO telescope. I have an old Nikon D7000. I would like to get started with astrophotography as well, I know I need a T-ring to connect DSLR to telescope. However, are there additional parts needed? I searched and found that I might also need T-ring adapter or a field flattener, in addition to the T-ring. Is this necessary? Please let me know. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: be aware that your camera will have an IR filter in it - if you get to like astrophotography you'll probably end up buying a dedicated astro-camera

Comment: Also, be aware that you may not be able to focus your DSLR because of the sensor position:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48464/camera-adaptor-wont-focus

Answer (score 3):

All you need are:

1. A Nikon to T-ring adapter
2. A T-ring to 1.25" eyepiece adapter

They are often sold together.

This allows you to connect the camera as if it were another eyepiece.  Of course, there's no limit to additional accessories you could use, but that's all you need to get started.

Comment: +1 but I'm curious 1) how you can tell that the telescope's [Explore Scientific 2" rack-and-pinion focuser](https://explorescientificusa.com/products/ed80-essential-series-air-spaced-triplet-refractor) uses 1.25" eyepieces and 2) what keeps the camera (being held by the eyepiece mount) from simply sliding out and landing on the ground when the telescope is pointed at the zenith?

Comment: @uhoh Pretty much all 2" eyepiece holders also have an adapter for 1.25" eyepieces.  They have a small thumb screw to hold the camera from sliding out or rotating.

Comment: I would like to get started with prime focus imaging and not through the eye-piece.I have a refractor telescope so I can directly expose the camera sensor through the telescope instead of going through an eye piece.

Comment: @UdayShankarS the "eyepiece adapter" is what you use for prime focus, it's called that because it replaces the eyepiece.  Taking a photo through the eyepiece is called "eyepiece projection" and requires a different adapter.